# 7 tokens is add to prompt_tokens in gpt-3.5-turbo

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I use https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions api and in every response 7 tokens is added more to prompt_tokens,but token calculation is different in documentation
`(https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/introduction)`

"prompt_tokens" must be 1 for "content": "pear" in documentation but api response is 8

```
Request:
{
     "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
        {
             "role": "user",
            "content": "pear"
         }
    ]
 }
Response:
{
     "id": "chatcmpl-6rQXcOtA0wOoYIbTJEvBrjL9CvN6i",
   "object": "chat.completion",
     "created": 1678191428,
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
     "usage": {
         "prompt_tokens": 8,
        "completion_tokens": 122,
         "total_tokens": 130
     },
    "choices": [
         {
             "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "\n\nA pear is a type of fruit that is commonly eaten in many parts of the world. Pears are usually sweet and juicy with a soft flesh that is rich in vitamins and minerals. It is a good source of dietary fiber, potassium, vitamin C, and copper. Pears come in a variety of shapes, sizes, and colors, with some having a green, yellow, or reddish-brown skin. They are often eaten raw as a snack, used in salads, baked into desserts, or cooked in savory dishes. Pears are also made into juice, jams, and other preserves."
             },
             "finish_reason": "stop",
             "index": 0
         }
     ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt token not only just contains content, but whole messages. Here it is:

```
{
 "role": "user",
 "content": "pear"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it formats your prompt into a known format to the model and then calculates the number of tokens in your prompt
more explanation is here
https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb
Paragraph #6. Counting tokens for chat completions API calls

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C # code that can help you calculate the accurate message tokens count for OpenAI models:

```
[Fact]
public void Run()
{
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> exampleMessages =
    [
        new() {
            {"role", "user"},
            {"content", "What is OpenAI?"}
        }
    ];

    int count = this.CalculateTokensCountForMessage(exampleMessages);

    WriteLine(count);
}


public int CalculateTokensCountForMessage(List<Dictionary<string, string>> messages)
{
    int tokensPerMessage = 3;
    int tokensPerName = 1;
    GptEncoding encoding = GptEncoding.GetEncoding("cl100k_base");

    //if (model == "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301")
    //tokensPerMessage = 4; // every message follows <|start|>{role/name}\n{content}<|end|>\n
    //tokensPerName = -1; // if there's a name, the role is omitted

    int numTokens = 0;

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        numTokens += tokensPerMessage;

        foreach (var item in message)
        {
            List<int> tokens = encoding.Encode(item.Value);

            numTokens += tokens.Count;

            if (item.Key == "name")
            {
                numTokens += tokensPerName;
            }
        }
    }

    numTokens += 3; //every reply is primed with <|start|>assistant<|message|>

    return numTokens;
}
```

[Sharp Token](https://github.com/dmitry-brazhenko/SharpToken)